# Dual Linear Program for Load Balancing - how to write the dual of an LP with summations?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, duality-theorems

Load Balancing Problem: The input consists of $n$ jobs $J_1, J_2, \dots J_n$ and an integer $m$ denoting the number of machines. The size of $J_i$ is a non-negative number $s_i$. The goal is to assign the jobs to machines while minimizing the makespan (minimize the largest load of any machine).

Below is the primal linear program that I written where $l$ is the makespan load and $x_{ij}$ is an indicator variable that equals $1$ when job $J_i$ is assigned to machine $j$ and $0$ otherwise.

$min: l$

$\sum_{j=1}^{m}x_{ij} = 1 $  $\forall 1\leq i\leq n$

$l \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}s_ix_{ij}$  $\forall 1\leq j \leq m$

$x_{ij} \geq 0$

How would you write the primal for this dual? I am confused on how to convert this into a dual because of the summations and the irregular format. I have tried writing dual linear programs for similar programs (max-flow to min-cut LP), but struggle to write the dual each time.

I am **studying for an exam** and this was  a practice problem provided in the review. Any tips on how to approach creating duals for these more complicated linear programs would be very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: At your second constraint you sum over all $j$. So it should be $\forall 1\leq \color{red}i\leq m$. Or did you want to sum over all $i$?

Comment: @callculus Thank you for catching that error. I've updated the problem with the correct constraint. I meant to sum over all $i$.

Comment: What is the range of $l$? Is it non-negative?

Comment: @callculus Yes. $l$ is non-negative at it represents the makespan load. The makespan load is calculated from a machine's job sizes $s_i$, which is also positive.

Comment: The difficulty I have that on one hand your write "$x_{ij}$ is an indicator variable that equals $1$ when job $J_i$ is assigned to machine $j$ and $0$ otherwise" and on the other hand $$x_{ij}\geq 0$$ What is true?

Comment: @callculus The variable $x_{ij}$ is an indicator variable. $x_{ij}=1$ when job $J_i$ is assigned to machine $j$. $x_{ij}=0$ if job $J_i$ is **not** assigned to machine $j$. The constraint $x_{ij}\geq 0$ ensures that $x_{ij}$ is nonnegative. The first constraint ensures that the value of $x_{ij}$ is at most $1$. Thus, the constraint $x_{ij} \geq 0$ is implicitly binds the value of $x_{ij}$ to be either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: If $x_{ij}$ is a binary variable, then the constraint $x_{ij}\geq 0$ is redundant, since $\{0,1\}\subseteq \mathbb R_0^+$. And as far as I know, for a program with binary variables a dual program is not possible.

Comment: Your second constraint is the wrong sense.

Comment: If you relax the binary variable to $\ge 0$, the interpretation is that a job can be split across machines.  If you are being asked to construct the dual, that interpretation must be what was intended.